# Jest minimal report on Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, jestjs

I just ran jest on one test file containing multiple tests inside.

This is the output I see whenever I run the jest command:

`Using Jest CLI v0.4.0
Waiting on 1 test...
 PASS  src\__tests__\index-tests.js (1.107s)
1 test passed (1 total)
Run time: 1.36s
----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
File      |   % Stmts |% Branches |   % Funcs |   % Lines |
----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
All files |       100 |       100 |       100 |       100 |
----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|`

(no detailed report of what tests actually succeeded).
Whenever a test fails I would only see that one and not a detailed report - for example 2 out of 3 tests passed.

How can I make jest use a more verbose mode?

P.S.
I tried using 'setupTestFrameworkScriptFile' option and using a script file to set jasmine.VERBOSE = true, but it seems like it has no effect on the output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the wanted behavior - be as simple as possible. No way to extend the output without adding a new feature to the framework.